# Direct assignment to the forward side of a many-to-many set is prohibited. Use morador.set() instead

Tags: django, django-rest-framework

Estou construindo uma API, para um sistema de condomínio, e ao tentar selecionar os moradores, recebo a seguinte exceção:

```
TypeError at /apartamento/
Direct assignment to the forward side of a many-to-many set is prohibited. Use morador.set() instead
```

Como a própria exceção sugere, tentei usar o set para salvar os moradores, entretanto, somente o último morador selecionado é salvo. Também tentei usando add e o mesmo acontece.

**Model**

```
class Apartamento(models.Model):
    numero = models.CharField(max_length=10, null=False, blank=False)
    condominio = models.ForeignKey(Condominio, on_delete=models.CASCADE)
    morador = models.ManyToManyField(Usuario, related_name='moradia')

    class Meta:
        db_table = 'apartamento'
        verbose_name = 'Apartamento'
        verbose_name_plural = 'Apartamentos'

    def __str__(self):
        return self.numero
```

**View**

```
class ApartamentoView(viewsets.ModelViewSet):
    queryset = Apartamento.objects.all()
    serializer_class = ApartamentoSerializer

    def create(self, request):
        condominio = Condominio.objects.get(id=request.data['condominio'])
        morador = Usuario.objects.get(id=request.data['morador'])
        Apartamento.objects.create(numero=request.data['numero'], condominio=condominio, morador=morador)

        headers = self.get_success_headers(request.data)

        return Response(
            {'Message' : 'Apartamento cadastrado com sucesso!'},
            status=status.HTTP_201_CREATED,
            headers=headers
        )
```

Comment: quando vc tenta registrar só um funciona e quando tenta registrar vários não funciona? qual a multiplicidade de `Apartamento` com `Condominio`?

Comment: Sim, se eu registrar só um morador funciona, se eu registrar mais de um ele só salva o ultimo. 1 condomínio para n apartamentos

Comment: nesse caso acho que vc deveria usar um `for` para iterar entres os moradores e conseguir adiciona-los

Comment: ah não esqueça que quando temos um campo com `many-to-many` vc deve usar `add` ou `set` veja a [doc](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/2.2/topics/db/examples/many_to_many/)